# Como subir el scroll de un modal bootstrap con js

Tags: javascript, modal

lo que sucede es que tengo una modal bootstrap donde muestro una lista, lo que me gustaría saber es como puedo con una instrucción  javascript reiniciar ese scroll asi como "window.scrollTo(0, 0);" ya he intentado varias cosas pero no me funciona.

este es lo que he intentado pero no me funciona

```
document.getElementById("Modalfil").scrollTop(0, 0);
```

```
y este el el modal que tiene un scroll de pie a cabeza 

<div class="modal fade right" id="Modalfil" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalPreviewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog-full-width modal-dialog momodel modal-fluid" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content-full-width modal-content ">
      <div class="modal-header-full-width   modal-header text-center ">
                
       
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-white fixed-top" style="-webkit-box-shadow: -2px 3px 5px -1px rgba(214,211,214,1);-moz-box-shadow: -2px 3px 5px -1px rgba(214,211,214,1);
box-shadow: -2px 3px 5px -1px rgba(214,211,214,1);">
    <div class="container">
     <button type="button" class="close" style="margin-left:2px" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-light fas fa-shopping-cart" id="car" onclick="listcar();" style="color:#11DBEC;margin-top:0px;margin-left:70%; border-radius:100px;" ><?php echo ' '.$varcar?></button>

      
                 <div class="scrollmenu " style="text-align: center;background-color:#FFF;margin-top:20px"  id="cat"></div>
           
   
    </div>
  </nav>
        

     </div>
     <br><br><br>
        <div class="modal-body">
             
               <div  style="-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(150,148,150,1);-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(150,148,150,1);
                  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(150,148,150,1);background-color:#fff;border-radius:10px" id="container">
            
        <div  style="border-radius:10px" id="filtro"></div>
        
      </div>
       
             
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, adjunta el código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: ya puse el código del modal el cual se le activa un scroll por defecto lo que requiero es como hacer que el scroll este en 0 en determinado momento con js

Comment: Acabo de ver la actualizacion del codigo, creo que la respuesta no te sera util

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentar usar un boton y agregarle un evento onClick

```js
let toTopBtn = document.getElementById("toTopBtn");

window.onscroll = function() {scrollBtn()};

function scrollBtn(){
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10){
        toTopBtn.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        toTopBtn.style.display = "none";
    }
};

function toTop() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  };
```

```css
#container{
  height: 120vh;
  background: red;
   }
#toTopBtn{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
  color: green;
  border:blue;
    }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<button id='toTopBtn' onclick="toTop()">subir</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

¿A qué elemento quieres que se le haga scroll? en tu ejemplo no existe un elemento con id 'list'

Suponiendo que tienes una lista de divs así:

```
<div id="lista">
    <div>element</div>
    <div>element</div>
    <div>element</div>
    <div>element</div>
    <div>element</div>
    <div>element</div>
    <div>element</div>
    <div>element</div>
    <div>element</div>
</div>
```

Está bien como lo estás haciendo siempre y cuando el la lista a la que quieras hacer scroll tenga esa forma. Es decir, el elemento al que le harás scroll es el que realmente tiene scroll.

```
document.querySelector("#lista").scrollTop(0, 0);
```

o

```
document.getElementById("lista").scrollTop(0, 0);
```

Además tienes que asegurarte de que la instrucción javascript se ejecute cuando la lista ya esté disponible en el navegador porque si no puede estar ejecutándose antes de que exista y cuando aparezca ya no hará scroll. Esto lo puedes ejecutar justo despues de levantar el modal.

Comment: en realidad no es list es Modalfil  el scroll  que quiero hacer es de todo el modal